# Is WeBlog compatible with Azure PaaS?

Tags: paas, weblog

As we know when we run a Sitecore instance on Azure PaaS we have to use Azure Search instead of Solr or Lucene.

Since WeBlog does have custom configs for Content Search, I'm wondering if they are compatible with Azure Search.

If they are not, what are the changes required to make it work on such environment?

This is a CMS-Only instance running on 8.2 update 7

Comment: Sitecore supports using Solr on SearchStax when using XP on Azure PaaS

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box, WeBlog uses custom index based on Lucene. You can try patching that config to use Azure Search.